# Count Instance of text and run bat if a number is reached

Tags: jscript, wsh

I am using indexOf to count "200" in a string, I need to find a way to count the 200 as 1 instead of (if string was "200") 3. is there a way to do this? here is what i have so far...

```
    var objIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    objIE.Navigate("URL of site");
    WScript.Sleep(2000);
    var str = objIE.Document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    var n = str.indexOf("200");
    if (n = 3){
WshShell.Run("killexplorer.bat");
    } 
    else {
    WshShell.Run("domanual.vbs")
    }
```

note: the internalHTML has a total of one (2) and five zero's.

Comment: This isn't javascript, it's vbscript (or wscript).  It runs on Windows, part of the `Windows Script Host`.  You should re-tag your question so the right people will see your question, it also has *very little* to do with `batch-file`...

Comment: @JamesL. - it is a `jscript` not exactly `javascript` but definitely not `vbscript`.

Comment: no matter what it is, if the syntax is correct I'm not to particular on the technicalities.